# Configuring ArcGIS Enterprise Deployment using reverse proxy

Tags: proxy, arcgis-enterprise, arcgis-web-adaptor

I'm attempting to install an ArcGIS Enterprise base deployment using a reverse proxy configuration. The company I'm contracting for had most of the installation complete already, but our client apps were unable to reach the REST services through the Web Adaptor and I believe the Web Adaptor configuration is the point of failure, so I uninstalled it. However, I'm having trouble reinstalling it.

ArcGIS Server and Portal for ArcGIS are running on a server behind the firewall. Two Web Adaptors are running on a DMZ server which is also the reverse proxy. One points to ArcGIS Server and the other to Portal.

Is this the correct place for each component?

Do the Web Adaptors need to have a second instance of Portal or ArcGIS Server running on the same machine before they can be configured to point to the instances behind the firewall with the services I need?

Comment: Is this installed Windows or Linux?

Comment: Kindly include the version information as well

Comment: It is installed on a Windows server. The version of ArcGIS Enterprise is 10.7.1

Comment: A logical architecture diagram of what you have would also be worth including. 
This might be worth a read over: http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Information_Security#Web_and_ArcGIS_Server_components_in_DMZ

To answer your question.  Yes, your setup should work.  We need more information to identify exactly how to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your Setup is infact the most commonly used setup. Make sure the https/http ports used by portal and server are open in your firewall because you will need them to configure webadaptor with your portal and server machines from DMZ.

See the documentation for [Firewalls and ArcGIS Server](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/linux/firewalls-and-arcgis-server.htm).